# ASP MVC Image Upload Error “The input is not a valid Base-64 string”

Tags: asp.net-mvc, base64, image-upload

I have this form where I'm trying to upload an image. WhenI click the submit button, I get the following error:

"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

The controller is never reached, as the error happens as soon as I upload the image. I'm at a loss what to do. Any help is appreciated!

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Create", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ComponentModel.Image, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <a class="btn" href="javascript:;">
                Choose File...
                <input type="file" name="Image" Size="40" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 0; left: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); opacity: 0; background-color: transparent; color: transparent"
                       onchange='$("#upload-file-info").html($(this).val());'/>
            </a>
            <span class="label label-info" id="upload-file-info"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

UPDATE:

This is the Create controller:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(Component component, HttpPostedFileBase image = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
                component.Image = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                image.InputStream.Read(component.Image, 0, image.ContentLength);
            }
            componentRepository.InsertComponent(component);
            componentRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", component);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really haven't provided enough information here, but I'm going to take a wild guess based on the error message.

You say it's not hitting your controller, but it kind of *has* to be hitting your controller. The error comes from ASP.NET, so it's going back to the server.

You've bound the file input to `Image`, and my guess is that `Image` is a byte array on your model. You can't post directly to a byte array. You need to bind to a property of type `HttpPostedFileBase`, from which you can then read the byte array and set it on your other property.

Comment: I've updated the OP with the controller. I've already been thinking about what you suggest, but unfortunately it didn't change anything. If I put a breakpoint in the controller, it never gets hit.

Comment: That's because the error is being generated by the modelbinder, before it actually gets to your action code. Because you have a property on `Component` called `Image`, the modelbinder attempts to bind the data there, which is what's causing the error. The fact that you have another parameter called `image` never comes into play. You need to use a name for the input (and parameter) that's distinct from anything on your model.

Comment: I've added a HttpPostedFileBase property to the model which got rid of the error and allowed me to upload the file. What would be the next course of action here? Converting the HttpPostedFileBase parameter into a byte[] and storing that instead?

Comment: If the "model" is your entity, you shouldn't have the HttpPostedFileBase property on it. Either use a view model, or bind it to an additional parameter as you attempted to do previously. However, yes, once you have the the posted file, you need to read the bytes from the stream and set the appropriate property on your model with that.

Answer (score 0):

`public HttpPostedFileBase image { get; set; }` Use it on your model
`<input type="file" name="image" />` Use it on your View name prop should be same as HttpPostedFileBase image and catch it on post method and after convert it into byte